# How to run docker-compose up -d at system start up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

To let the containers autostart at startup point, I tried to add the command:

`cd directory_has_docker-compose.yml && docker-compose up -d`   in /etc/rc.local.

but then after I rebooted the machine, the containers did not work.

How can I run `docker-compose up -d` at system start up?

Answer (score 303):

When we use `crontab` or the deprecated `/etc/rc.local` file, we need a delay (e.g. `sleep 10`, depending on the machine) to make sure that system services are available. Usually, `systemd` (or `upstart`) is used to manage which services start when the system boots. You can try use the similar configuration for this:

```bash
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service

[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/srv/docker
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or, if you want run without the `-d` flag:

```bash
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service

[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=60

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/docker
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Change the `WorkingDirectory` parameter with your dockerized project path. And enable the service to start automatically:

```bash
systemctl enable docker-compose-app
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to test if it works without restarting raspberry?

Comment: @dmigo `systemctl start docker-compose-app` and `systemctl status docker-compose-app` are what you're looking for I think.

Comment: not worked for me, when I run `systemctl start docker-compose-app` encountered with this: `Job for docker-compose-app.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker-compose-app.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari When you run `journalctl -xe`, is there any useful information?

Comment: @OlegBelostotsky I create this fike `/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service` and copy paste your answer, then ran `systemctl enable docker-compose-app` but not any changed, then I ran `systemctl start docker-compose-app` and `systemctl status docker-compose-app` and get above mentioned error!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari You should change the parameter `WorkingDirectory` to your own, for your project. If you continue to get an error, just execute the command `journalctl -xe` in your console.

Comment: @OlegBelostotsky I did it, and it service created well, I could running docker-compose with `systemctl start docker-compose-app` or `service docker-compose-app start`, but after a reboot, the service came down, so I get its status with `systemctl status docker-compose-app` and saw failed status, then I did start again manually for start. how can I have docker-compose-app.service autostart? using rc.local?

Comment: What about Mac OS X? There is no `systemd` or `upstart` for Mac

Comment: @dmigo: test startup of your service with: `service docker-compose-app start`, status with `service docker-compose-app status`, stop with `service docker-compose-app stop`

Comment: Best answer IMHO. @OlegBelostotsky could you provide explanation about why the non-detached version adds further directives?`Restart=on-failure; StartLimitIntervalSec=60; StartLimitBurst=3`

Comment: Remark: with the change of docker compose form the soon deprecated standalone version (docker-compose) to the now preferred and long-term supported plugin version (docker compose) the syntax of the binary in ExecStart and ExecStop changes. Info about docker compose versions: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. See the answers below. The reason being is it's not portable. You move your docker-compose to a different server and it doesn't behave in the same way. With the solution below using the restart:always in the file docker itself deals with the startup of the services. Provided you have docker installed properly it then takes care of things, which is the *right* way.

Answer (score 292):

If your `docker.service` enabled on system startup

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker
```

and your services in your `docker-compose.yml` has

```
restart: always
```

all of the services run when you reboot your system if you run below command only once

```
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: Why "restart: always" and not "restart: unless-stopped"? Both should do the work I would say

Comment: @rastov both of them are similar but in unless-stopped when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.

Comment: "if _you_ run below command only once" - but, the point of a process manager like systemd or init.d is to remove the human in the loop. To get the human out, one needs @oleg-belostotsky's tactic.

Comment: @Lonnie the run once is equivalent to adding the crontab. basically start the compose once, and `restart: always` will take care of the rest.

Comment: This will start all containers of the docker-compose.yml at the *same* time and not in the dependency order defined.

Comment: It seems that restart option does not start all containers in due order as docker compose start or up do, at least, after implementing the healthchecks and depend conditions, it seems to ignore it upon system restart.

Answer (score 249):

You should be able to add:

```
restart: always
```

to every service you want to restart in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

See: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#restart

Comment: Keep in mind that they have to be running when a reboot occurs, so don't manually stop them before the reboot.

Comment: some services such as Nginx not starts with this option even.

Comment: This is the proper answer to the question. There is a designed way to restart containers, why get into cron jobs and other ways to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is the right answer. When you start using Kubernetes instead of cron, you'll be happy you used it.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui Note that `restart: always` has some serious bugs: host mounts will not be attached on reboot for example. In my opinion, it's better to reinvent the wheel, if the existing wheel is square.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this solution, because it implies that you have the whole docker/docker-compose stack installed and configured in default mode. In case you use a different folder for your docker-compose.yml file, it doen't work at all.

Comment: You can't rely on this solution if you have environment variables in your yaml file

Comment: Why "restart: always" and not "restart: unless-stopped"? Both should do the work I would say

Comment: unless-stopped is similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.

Comment: for the people wondering, the above line should be added to every service. (not at the top of the file afaik)

Comment: This doesn't defend against when you do `docker-compose down` and forget to spin it back up `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @okdewit is this still the case in 2023? Presumably this bug? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1192

Comment: Too often, this method does not work well, because services may start in the wrong order & other issues may arise. It's best to cycle them properly, with `docker compose`.

Comment: This will start all containers of the docker-compose.yml at the *same* time and not in the dependency order defined.

Answer (score 49):

Use **restart: always** in your `docker-compose.yaml` file.

`Docker-compose up -d` will launch container from images again. Use `docker-compose start` to start the stopped containers, it never launches new containers from images.

```yaml
nginx:   
    restart: always   
    image: nginx   
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - other_container:other_container
```

Also you can write the code up in the docker file so that it gets created first, if it has the dependency of other containers.

Comment: You may not want to use `always`, but maybe `unless-stopped`. Other options are `on-failure` and `no`. This is known as a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

Comment: Just adding that line should work? Is there a tutorial on how to enable this whole solution? Thanks!

Comment: After adding the line `restart: always`, run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d` again to make it effective. `docker-compose start/restart` won't reflect the change in yaml.

Answer (score 45):

I tried `restart: always`, it works at some containers(like php-fpm), but i faced the problem that some containers(like nginx) is still not restarting after reboot.

Solved the problem.

```
crontab -e

@reboot (sleep 30s ; cd directory_has_dockercomposeyml ; /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d )&
```

Comment: You should be suspicuous of bare sleeps as they introduce non-deterministic behavior: https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html#AsynchronousBehavior

Comment: @giorgiosironi sleep is fine in this case. Container start-up must be able to handle nondeterministic behaviour anyway.

Comment: It's also introducing up to 30 seconds of latency that may not be needed.

Comment: @z0r sleep is not fine! Sleep may "work" but any startup sequence should be deterministic. Linux services use dependencies to ensure things like the network are available etc. before they start. You should do the same.

Answer (score 14):

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

> docker-compose.yml

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, otherwise it will not be considered to be a good answer.

Comment: you can deduce from the most popular answer that this is saying it's a refinement on that answer, to allow for users to manually stop

Comment: One can always manually stop a container. The difference between `always` and `unless-stopped` is that containers won't start on bootup with `unless-stopped` if the container was manually stopped. If you manually stop a `restart: always` container it will remain stopped until the next boot. (or rather, the next time the docker daemon restarts). 
One can't really deduce this information from the most popular answer. 1. the most popular answer is currently a systemd service file answer. 2. the next most popular answer doesn't provide these details. One has to read the manpage for `docker-run`

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to `user39544`'s answer, one more type of syntax for `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /path_to_your_project/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: This worked for me in Mar 2018 on a RPi3 running Raspian. I ran `crontab -e` as user pi, with pi a member of group docker...

Answer (score 1):

To use restart policies, Docker provides the following options:

> no: Containers won't restart automatically.
>
> on-failure[:max-retries]: Restart the container if it exits with a
> non-zero exit code, and provide a maximum number of attempts for the
> Docker daemon to restart the container.
>
> always: Always restart the container if it stops.
>
> unless-stopped: Always restart the container unless it was stopped
> arbitrarily, or by the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me(slight variant):

> crontab -e
> then pick nano editor, if not yet selected.
> at the bottom of file add as one line from @reboot to &:

> @reboot (sleep 10s ; cd /usr/local/searxng-docker ; /usr/bin/docker-compose up -d )&

> Based upon a common location of "docker-compose" and the
> "searxng-docker" folder. It forces the 2 commands "cd to
> the actual searxng-docker folder" and run the container startup "docker-compose up -d" command.