# PostgreSQL container doesn't use environment variables when ran by a startup script

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, arm

I want my docker containers to run when my Raspberry PI boots, so I created a service that executes on startup following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671482/how-to-run-docker-compose-up-d-at-system-start-up/53569049).

This is the created service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service

[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/asset-tracking/laradock
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d nginx beacon-clocking mongo postgres
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything seems to run smoothly when I reboot the system, but when I access the login page I end up getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "boilerplate_user" (SQL: select * from "settings")
```

Now, boilerplate_user is one of the environment variables used to login to the postgres database, but it looks like the container has no idea about them.
Running `docker ps` shows that the container is running along with the others.

I tried getting into the postgres container and logging into postgres using the environment variables but it says that `role boilerplate_user does not exist`

The weird thing, though, is that if I do `docker-compose up -d postgres` with the container already ran by the service, it won't say it's up-to-date but it looks like it runs it like it wasn't running already in the first place. After running it a second time, I am able to log into the database using the `boilerplate_user` and the login page on my application works like a charm.

I've also tried disabling the service and running the script manually after the reboot. When I do it this way, I am able to log in using `boilerplate_user`.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` for the postgres container:

```
### PostgreSQL ###########################################
    postgres:
      restart: always
      build: ./postgres
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ${POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - backend
```

I expect the postgres container to use the env variables without having to manually ssh into the system after every reboot to restart the container (or start it for good).