# How to "reset" a docker-compose systemd service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd

I have created a `systemd` service that starts a set of Docker containers using Docker-Compose, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066454/1228454):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service

[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/srv/docker
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This allows me to start the Docker-Compose services using

```
sudo systemctl start docker-compose-app
```

which uses `docker-compose up -d` under the hood, and shutting them down using

```
sudo systemctl stop docker-compose-app
```

which uses `docker-compose down`. Please note that the `down` command is run without the `-v` flag, which means that volumes will remain in place, preserving the data of my containers across restarts/recreation. This is pretty much what I want in the majority of cases.

There are situations where I want to erase all data in the services, basically running the `down -v` command instead of just `down`.

Is there a way to extend the above `systemd` service definition to allow for an additional command (or using one of the existing `systemctl` commands) that would allow me to run the occasional `down -v` if needed. I want to do this ad-hoc if needed, not scheduled or anything like that.

How can I run

```
docker-compose down -v
```

occasionally if needed through the same `systemd` setup, while keeping the standard functionality of maintaining the containers' data across restarts?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use compose to handle the life-cycle, e.g. the ability to start the compose "service" automatically?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate? I have another systemd service that depends on the containers started by docker-compose, so need to ensure that docker-compose is up when the server starts. I thought it was convenient to use systemd for starting the containers. It works well in general, but then the question about the `down -v` came up...

Comment: You explained why you need to do it :).  Once I'm using containers, I try to keep it containers all the way down. Translation: I wouldn't have an OS service depend on something in a container if I could help it.

Comment: True - this is a Dev server, wouldn't do the same for production... The other driver is that I want to automate this through Ansible, and `systemd` services are well understood by Ansible. Maybe I just need to run the plain `docker-compose down -v` through Ansible's `shell` module if needed, everything else stays in `systemd` for handling server restarts...

Answer (score 5):

You may try to use `ExecReload` definition:

```
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down -v && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
```

And then you can use:

```
sudo systemctl reload docker-compose-app
```

So "reload" command will be used for "reset" in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give that a try.