# How to run elasticsearch nodes as service in linux

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I have some **elasticsearch** nodes (10 data nodes 1 master node).

I want to run all nodes as service.

I mean when systems reboot starts all nodes. How can i do this in **linux** systems ?

Thanks for answering

Comment: If it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671482/how-to-run-docker-compose-up-d-at-system-start-up/45193532

Comment: Thanks for answering, is it possible to create service for everynode without docker ? or docker is obligatory for this ?

Comment: If you are not very familiar with Linux, docker may be by far the easiest solution. I used this setup for production work and it was fine. You can run 10 nodes locally without docker, which means that you need 10 configuration files, 10 data folders, 10 ports etc. For sure it can be done, but why to bother. You can start with some tutorial like https://marcofranssen.nl/building-a-elasticsearch-cluster-using-docker-compose-and-traefik/ and then just add nodes. Up to you.