# Nginx Reverse Proxy Manager on Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't automatically start up after reboot

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I set up the Nginx Reverse Proxy Manager by Jamie Curnow on my Raspberry Pi using docker and docker-compose.

This is the yml stack file:

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    ports:
      - '80:80' #HTTP Traffic
      - '81:81' #Dashboard Port
      - '443:443' #HTTPS Traffic
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/app/config/production.json
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  db:
    image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:10.4'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'npm'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'npm'
      MYSQL_USER: 'npm'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'npm'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

(I use different passwords)

Now, I already once composed it using `sudo docker-compose up -d`, however, whenever I `sudo reboot` my Raspberry Pi, it doesn't start as a service.

This is my Raspberry Pi Kernel, btw:

```
Linux Pi-Server 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/L
```

And this is my OS version:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

The interesting part is that whenever I try to recompose it using `sudo docker-compose up -d` again, I get the following output:

```
Starting nginx_db_1  ... done
Starting nginx_app_1 ... done
```

Afterwards, both Nginx and its GUI by Mr. Curnow work.

Is there a more fancy way other than running this docker-compose on startup every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Host -- docker service level

Update: the initial answer works within docker itself. If you want docker itself to also start on boot, then that's a [different story](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot). You should be able to do that with:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```

---

### VM -- docker container level (nginx)

You can definitely start nginx service on boot.

The commands are self-explanatory -- **enable**, **disable**, and check **status** of running nginx on boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl disable nginx
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

Resources:

1. [Launch Nginx on startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/69350/launch-nginx-on-startup/994316).
2. [systemd examples](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/)

If this is not available at your disposal, let me know and I'll try to find other ways and update my answer.

Comment: Within docker you need to make sure nginx is started automatically on boot. But also what's hosting the nginx container (host/OS) also needs to be configured to let docker service itself start automatically on boot. (You can think of this like nested dreams in inception movie!)

Comment: Thank you for your help, no more help is required! I added another comment that explains how to add a service file that automatically runs the docker-compose. It's a workaround, your solutions are easier and to the same trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the YML file to say "`restart: always`" in the "`services:`"

for example like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.6.6
    ports:
      - 9932:5432
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  myapp:
    image: myapp
    links:
      - postgresql
    depends_on:
      - "postgresql"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I would also recommend adding your specific docker-compose as a service using this service directory:

```
/etc/systemd/system/
```

In here simply create the file using nano or vim. The filename is not important, however, it needs to be a ".service" file, so I recommend the name "`docker-compose-app.service`"

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/wherever/your/docker-compose/file/is
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(WorkingDirectory = wherever your docker-compose file is, please change!)

All you then need to do is:

```
systemctl enable docker-compose-app
```

(If you've given it a different file name, use that name here)

And just to be sure:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

This is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671482/how-to-run-docker-compose-up-d-at-system-start-up) which might help you answer your problem

How the [restart: always policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/884759/how-does-restart-always-policy-work-in-docker-compose) works.