# How to run docker compose at start up using cron

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron

I have added the following line to the end of my cron editor

@reboot sudo docker-compose up -d

But nothing is happening. Any idea how to get this to work? New to this so do not have much of a clue. I am looking to run this line in terminal when my server reboots. Thanks

Comment: you can use systemd to manage and start your Docker Compose service automatically on server boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run docker-compose up -d at system start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671482/how-to-run-docker-compose-up-d-at-system-start-up)